# Skills required to develop html5 application

Tags: html

what are the skills combination required to develop html5 application ?

Comment: silly,  please do understand my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML and javascript. If you want it to be pretty CSS would be helpful. And if you want it to be more dynamic a server side language is a must.

Personally I like [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) very much.

Comment: Sure, jquery always helps to write better javascript but it has nothing to do with HTML5 :-)

Comment: means we have to write old days javascript codes or what...

Comment: Means that there are features in HTML5 like WebSocket API and Local Storage which require you to write javascript (nothing to do with old days javascript) and are not yet covered by jquery because they are still a draft.

Comment: thanks Darin, is it worth learning html5 app development ?

Comment: @Sam3, that's very subjective. If you are going to work in the software industry then I guess it is worth. If you are going to work as I lawyer or a doctor then no, it is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be HTML5...

Answer (score 1):

HTML5, Javascript and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Programming and a bit of design.